# How to get value inside td using Dom

Tags: javascript, dom

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content_Data"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function auto()
{
alert("auto called");
document.getElementById('content_Data').innerHTML='<div><table><tr><td>10</td><td>20</td></tr></table></div>';
alert(document.getElementById('content_Data').innerHTML);
getelements();
}
function getelements(){


    var searchElement=document.getElementById('content_Data').getElementsByTagName("div");
    for( var i=0; i<searchElement.length; i++ )
    {
    var child_length=searchElement[i].childNodes.length; 

      for( j=0; j<child_length; j++ )
          {               
             alert(searchElement[i].childNodes[j].nodeValue);               
          }
     }

}
</script>
<script>auto();</script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

try looking at innerHTML of td node. Or if you want only text, then it is innerText for IE and textContent for others.

```
alert(searchElement[i].childNodes[j].innerHTML)
```

also, [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) will greatly simplify your code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, just navigate there. For example

```
document.getElementById('content_Data').firstChild.firstChild.firstChild
```

gets you the first table cell (with value 10).

Comment: Many browsers automatically insert a `<tbody>` when it is missing, but this isn't a guarantee. As such `.firstChild.firstChild... etc` will be unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `getElementsByTagName("div")` to get the `td` elements:

```
var searchElement=document.getElementById('content_Data').getElementsByTagName("td");
```

And, it's better to declare the `j` variable on the second `for` :D. That's all you need to change